# Run Web crawler in VSCode, got error: Cannot recover from stack overflow

Tags: python, web-crawler, stack-overflow

I wrote a web crawler, which is supposed to crawl through all hyperlinks under one domain name. I tried it with a very simple web page, it worked, but when I was trying it with a complicated website, it ran for half hour and finally returned this error Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Can anybody help take a look at the main function, see if there is any thing wrong?

```
visited = set()                                                                     
storedlinks = set()  

def crawler(url):                                                                   
    'Take an url, crawl all links under that domain name.'
    visited.add(url)                                                                
    if linkchunk in url:                 # Check if under the domain                                                         
        storedlinks.add(url)                                                                
        links = analyze(url)             # analyze is function to get hyperlinks                                                    

        counter = 0
        for link in links:               # Check new links                                                   
            if link in visited:          # Check if it's visited
                counter += 1         
                if counter == len(links):  # if all link in visited, then stop
                    break
            else:                                                                       
                try:                                                                    
                    print(link)
                    crawler(link)
                except:                                                                 
                    pass

    return storedlinks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just mean that you have a deep recursion and it ran out of stack space.  You can either add something to control your recursion depth or change this to a more iterative approach.  That's why a simple website with smaller recursion depth then you're fine.

I would use an iterative approach with a while loop, and shove any "new" url that need to process into a list and while that list is not empty, pull one out to crawl and repeat.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try while loop see if I can solve it.

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't look like a while loop can solve it, because during the process of iterating through the hyperlinks of the first url, we may need to repeat the process for each of the hyperlinks of the first url, then each links in the multiple hyperlink groups of the first generation of hyperlinks, and on and on. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was thinking something like traversing a graph.  See breath first or depth first in graph traversal see if it's applies to what you're trying to do.  You start by push the starting url into the queue.  While the queue is not empty, pop the front, do what you need to do and push any new encountered url that's not in your visited set into the queue.  Repeat this process until the queue is empty.